# How to define []= and at() = for a custom collection?

Tags: c++

**EDIT:** This question is not for overriding the operator `[]` I know how to do that

I have implemented My own collection class, and for assigning data I would like to provide the same operators/functions as `std::vector`. 
However, I have not been able to find a way to define the operators `[index]=elm` and `at(index) = elm`.

I am not even completely sure what to terms to search for as these two are not exactly operators

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: There's no operator `at` - it is a function in `std` containers. And, for `[]`, there is `operator[]`.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) on how the `operator[]` should be declared.  `at` will match that.

Comment: Notice how I write `[]=` and `at()=` not `[]` and `at()` only. The two later I have already overridden :)

Comment: Your `operator[]` and `at` function should return a reference to an element of your collection - you don't need to add anything to have assignment to those work

Comment: @LarsNielsen: "*Notice how I write []= and at()= not [] and at() only.*" There is no such thing as `[]=` or `at()=`. It's merely `[]` *followed by* an `=`.

Comment: @NicolBolas thank you :) Also why I wrote that these are not exactly operators, I just had zero clue what it was called :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `[]=` operator. If your `operator[]` function returns a reference that can be assigned to, that's all you need.

Simple example to demonstrate the idea.

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;
    int& operator[](int) { return i; };
    int operator[](int) const { return i; };
}
```

Now you can use

```
Foo f;
f[10] = 20;   // The index is not used by Foo::operator[]
              // This is just to demonstrate the syntax.
```

You need to do the same with the `at()` function.

Answer (score 4):

Define your `operator[]` overload and your `at` function to return a reference to the specified item. You can then assign the new value through that reference.